# How to back up DSLR pictures with Android?

Tags: backup

I'm going to be traveling soon and taking a DSLR camera and Galaxy S5 mobile phone. **How could I transfer the pictures to my phone and then to a backup service such as DropBox or Google Drive?** I anticipate taking more than 100 GB of pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Wi-fi memory cards! That is, if your camera doesn't have Wi-fi capability itself.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye-Fi

A comparison between two brands:

http://www.dpreview.com/articles/4616822206/battle-of-the-wi-fi-cards-eye-fi-vs-transcend

It's pretty cool stuff. Quoting from dpreview:

> Eye-Fi and Transcend wireless cards can both connect to a smartphone or tablet, providing the ability to wirelessly transfer images and videos to the device.